# How to write the magic function(__get and __set) of php7's class by c language

Tags: php, c, class

How to write the magic function(`__get` and `__set`) of PHP7's class in C language. I tried to solve it myself, but I found that it is too difficult for me.

**My questions**：

1. what meaning is the last argument of function named `zend_read_property`?
2. How to return the property value of the object (return `NULL` if not exist)?

**My code**：

```
ZEND_METHOD(Cheetah_Kernel_Object,__get) {
    char *name;
        int name_len;
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS()TSRMLS_CC, "s", &name, &name_len)
            == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL()
    }

    zend_class_entry *ce = Z_OBJCE_P(getThis());
    zend_read_property(ce, getThis(), name, name_len, 0 TSRMLS_CC, {??});
    RETURN_NULL()
}
```

Comment: supplement: the environment is php7

Comment: Shouldn't `zend_read_property()` be called like: `zend_read_property(ce, getThis(), name, name_len, FALSE, 0 TSRMLS_CC)`

Comment: @Cyclone but the zend_read_property is:
ZEND_API zval *zend_read_property(zend_class_entry *scope, zval *object, const char *name, size_t name_length, zend_bool silent, zval *rv);
what the meaning of *rv? return value?